# MBP 16 can't remember which monitor is which

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I've been running a 2019 MBP 16 with 2 (different) monitors fine for 2 years, I upgraded to 2 identical monitors and every time the MBP wakes up from sleep or restart it's as though it randomly chooses the output so that I have to then use 'Displays' to rearrange them.

Notes:

- MBP never forgets the rotation and resolution of the 2 external monitors - just which port is which
- both connected by USB-C to laptop - it doesn't matter if I swap ports
- both are connected via display port on the monitors
- both are: Samsung LU32J590UQUXEN 32-Inch 4K Ultra HD 3840 x 2160 LED Monitor
- occurs after both sleep and restart
- occurs on both existing user profile and when setup a new user on laptop
- Apple don't know what's wrong - just said to reset various memory caches, safe mode etc - nothing worked
- having different resolution and rotation between monitors also doesn't work

My working theory:

- that both monitors have the same internal name/id against which the rotation/resolution/position etc is stored and that the MBP is grabbing by Id and getting it wrong

If the above is correct I cannot find a way to 'rename' the monitor I assume hardcoded

Seems like there should be an easy fix but it saps a lot of time each day resetting and the alternative of disabling sleep isn't viable.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try waking the displays manually before the computer.

Comment: I'll try it and report back - but that would be impractical as a longterm solution due to the positions of the buttons vs the layout